# How to assign static IP on home network

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, router, dhcp

I have a NetGear WNR2000 wireless router, and I'd like to be able to hardwire a server to it, and have that server host a number of things: Subversion, Artifactory, Jenkins CI, and maybe a few others. Basically, it would serve the role of my personal "build server" at the homestead.

The problem is, in my software I'll need a reliable (preferably static) URL to hit for working with this build server. For instance, my Artifactory server might live at:

```
http://<whatever-ip-router-assigns>:8080/artifactory/myrepo/
```

And in Ant buildscript, I need to hardcode that URL in order for my project to build correctly.

Not being a "network guy", what options do I have at my disposal? Static routes come to mind, but I've never set one up and am not even sure if that's the right solution. The server will be whatever is the newest release of Ubuntu Server.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: No need to simulate, you can actually assign static IPs on a home network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, and usually easy, to set up static IPs behind a NAT (192.168.1.*). For Ubuntu Server, you'll want to set up the /etc/network/interfaces file similar to this:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.11
        broadcast 192.168.1.255
        gateway 192.168.1.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.1.0
```

If you can change the DHCP setting on your router, it'd be best to have it start assigning somewhere after any static IPs or end before. For my home, I have static IPs given out starting at 192.168.1.50 and end at 192.168.1.255, leaving me with ~50 IPs to assign statically, which is more than I should ever need.

Comment: So the solution is a combination of manipulating this `interfaces` file as well as loggin into the router and altering its DHCP settings? Thats it?!?! Awesome! thanks!

Comment: You don't really HAVE to set the DHCP up that way, but I suggest it just to avoid any potential issues (server is shut down, new device comes onto the network and takes it's ip, what now?). There's also other ways to assign static IPs, but this'll be the best way for ubuntu server, which you probably won't be running X on.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, if your server once got an IP address assigned by the DHCP server, it will try to always get that address again in the future. The DHCP server might also try to keep assigning the same address to the same device.

If this isn't happening for you, simply assign a static IP address to your server. Or make a manual DHCP address reservation for your server (to make **sure** it will always get the same address).